# Google Maps API javascript: nearbysearch callback function not calling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback

I followed Google's documentation closely, but for some reason my callback function isn't being called.  I stripped everything down so that it should just show an alert, and it doesn't.  I've tried searching for the problem, but it's so simple I can't even figure out what to search for.  Any thoughts?

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(myMap);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

// this displays
alert("TESTING");

...

function callback(results, status) {

     // this does not display
     alert("WHY DOESNT THIS DISPLAY?");

}
```

I've also tried this:

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(myMap);
service.nearbySearch(request, function callback(results, status) {

alert("WHY DOESNT THIS WORK?");

});
```

Comment: Any javascript errors? Are you including the [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library) in the load of the API?

Comment: The Chrome addon [Javascript Errors Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-errors-notifie/jafmfknfnkoekkdocjiaipcnmkklaajd) isn't catching any. Is there another way to view errors?  I'm including the places library:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

Comment: Here's a link to the page:

http://www.glit.com/buy/store-locator/

You can use "60601" and "All Products" as inputs

Comment: It doesn't look like the call to nearbySearch is ever executed.

Comment: Any idea why the nearbySearch isn't executing, but the following alert is?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the console, you will see this warning:

*Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.*

That's what you got, an unexpected error.

You have included the API 3 times:

line#140

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCx9FbzJ-0Ck8gts9oq11nAZU7F6LjLq8Y&sensor=false">

            </script>
```

line#146:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

line 636:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&#038;ver=1.0.0'></script>
```

---

Remove the scripts from line#140 and line#636 and you will see both alerts

Answer (score 0):

```
function callback(results, status) {
```

should be:

```
function (results, status) {
```

Comment: Trying this, I get the same results. Here's the page:

http://www.glit.com/buy/store-locator/

You can use 60601 and All Products as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Is your request object/string valid? You're not setting `request` to anything in this snippet: googleplaces probably won't fire your callback if you didn't make a real requst.